# Zorn's lemma contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Based on Zorn's lemma, for $(A, \preceq)$ an arbitrary poset, if all the chains in $A$ have an upper bound, then $A$ has a maximal element. One can construct the following chain for any poset. Take an arbitrary $x \in A$ and initially define $C_0 = \{x\}$ then extend C as follows recursively
$$
C_i = C_{i-1} \cup \{y \in A :  z \preceq y \: \forall z \in C_{i-1}\}
$$
Now two scenarios can happen.

1. This chain has an upper bound (how can we prove this?), then based on the definition of the set $C$ this upper bound must belong to $C$, therefore it's a maximal element. So the question is do we really need Zorn's lemma, because there is always a maximal element in a poset by constructing the above chain.
2. This chain doesn't have an upper bound. Which means that for any poset we can construct a chain which doesn't have an upper bound and therefore we can't use Zorn's lemma on any poset.

Comment: $C$, also called the initial segment determined by $x$, need not be a chain, for an arbitrary poset $(A, \leq)$. By construction, $x$ is always an upper bound of $C$. The hypothesis of Zorn's lemma is much stronger than this. It asks for EVERY chain in the non-empty poset to have an upper bound. If that is the case, then the poset has a maximal element.

Comment: I edited the question. We can think of $C$ as all elements in $A$ comparable with $x$.

Comment: $C$ is still not a chain. There can be elements $y, z$ in the poset which are comparable with $x$ but not with each other.

Comment: Still not a chain! Consider for example the partial order of positive integers under divisibility, and take $x=2$. Then $C_0=\{2\}$ and $C_1$ contains all even numbers, but $6$ and $8$ are incomparable so already $C_1$ isn't a chain.

Answer (score 4):

Your $C$ is usually **not** a chain. For example, take as our poset the set of positive integers with the "divides" ordering: $a\preceq b$ means that $a\vert b$. Then for instance we have $$2\prec 6\mbox{ and }2\prec 8 \quad\mbox{ but }\quad6\not\preceq 8\mbox{ and }8\not\preceq 6.$$ So there's no way to apply the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma to the $C$s that you're interested in.

(Note, of course, that the example poset I give above does not satisfy the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma - for example, the set of powers of $2$ is a chain with no upper bound.)

Comment: True, I modified the chain defined. I think the issue is not constructing that chain but something else.

Comment: @user7829968 I don't understand your modified construction. Should $C_i$ be the set of $a$ which are above every element of $C_{i-1}$? If so, that *again* isn't a chain. If not, what is $C_i$? (Your use of "$:$" is confusing.)

Comment: @user7829968 Try a concrete example: in the case of the poset of positive integers ordered by divisibility, what should $C_3$ be if we start with $x=2$?

Comment: The basic idea is that we start with an element $C_0 = \{x\}$, then we find a $y \in A$ (if there is any) comparable with $x$ and that would be our $C_1$, i.e. $C_1 = \{x,y\}$, now we choose another element $z \in A$ such that z is comparable with $x,y$ and then add it to the previous set to make a new set $C_2=\{x,y,z\}$